# Rails 7 encrypted attribute causes non-existing length validation to fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption

I have a column named `value_cents` where money values are stored.  I'd like to encrypt this column.  I followed the rails 7 guides for setting up encryption.  I then added the following to the model:

```
encrypts :value_cents, deterministic: true
```

this column is an integer converted to money via the money-rails gem.  However, after setting encrypts, the column changes to "text" type and fails a length validation saying

```
value_cents is too long (maximum is 4 characters)
```

I don't have any such validation set on the column, and can't figure out where it's coming from.

I've dug through the docs and cannot figure out what is occurring here.  Have I missed something?  Any advice on how to set this up?